# Improper table head width rendered initially, which gets fixed automatically if one of Th is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have read a lot of stuff on this, but dint find any luck!

Problem :
I am using datatables to achieve sorting on a table. On UI I have four tabs, each having one table. Now everything works fine until I use the "sScrollY" property. As soon as I set some value to this, by default width of my 'thead' is changing from 100% to 100px. ('tbody' part of the table is rendered just the same way.) If I click on one of the 'th's ,which results in a table redraw call(fnDraw) internally, adjusts thead's width properly.

Please help me getting rid of this.

Solutions I have tried:

- setting table-layout: fixed; i have applied this style to all my tables
- setting overflow auto to the wrapper div that wraps 'thead' in case of "sScrollY"; tried this and it dint work
- call fnDraw on click of the tab; tried this, used the fn DrawCallback to confirm that draw method is called, but it dint rectify the thead's alignment.
- call fnColumnResizing() ; this only works of I put it inside window.resize() and then resize the window manually.
- set sWidth property while init-ing the datatables; this dint work either!

Code:
code I am using to init datatables is :

```
oTable = $('#dataTableId').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "t",
        "sScrollY": getDivHeight(), //getDivHeight() returns a string val eg. 300px
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "asStripeClasses": ['test', 'test'],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']], 
        "aoColumnDefs": [
                         { "bSortable": true,"aTargets": [ 0 ]},
                         { "bSortable": true,"aTargets": [ 1 ]},
                         { "bSortable": true,"aTargets": [ 2 ]},
                         { "bSortable": false,"aTargets": [ 4 ]},
                         { "bSortable": true,"aTargets": [ 4 ]},
                         { "bSortable": false,"aTargets": [ 5 ]}
                       ],
         "aoColumns": [null,null,null,{ "iDataSort": 4 },null,null,null]
    } );
```

Thanks and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `sScrollY` property, the following function gets called (`sY` = `sScrollY`)

```
/**
     * Adjust a table's width to take account of scrolling
     *  @param {object} oSettings dataTables settings object
     *  @param {node} n table node
     *  @memberof DataTable#oApi
     */
    function _fnScrollingWidthAdjust ( oSettings, n )
    {
        if ( oSettings.oScroll.sX === "" && oSettings.oScroll.sY !== "" )
        {
            /* When y-scrolling only, we want to remove the width of the scroll bar so the table
             * + scroll bar will fit into the area avaialble.
             */
            var iOrigWidth = $(n).width();
            n.style.width = _fnStringToCss( $(n).outerWidth()-oSettings.oScroll.iBarWidth );
        }
        else if ( oSettings.oScroll.sX !== "" )
        {
            /* When x-scrolling both ways, fix the table at it's current size, without adjusting */
            n.style.width = _fnStringToCss( $(n).outerWidth() );
        }
    }
```

I suspect that the `.width()` and `outerWidth()` are not working as intended for one of the following reasons:

1. functions are being called before the `$(window).load` event is fired. The solution to this would be to wrap the function inside a `$(window).load()`, instead of a `$(document).ready()`
2. You mentioned that you have several tabs with tables. If this is only happening on the tables that are in tabs which are initially hidden, its because some of the width commands don't work for hidden elements (display: none). See this example http://jsfiddle.net/XLET8/

The classic solution is to position the element off the screen, check the width, then hide it and put it back. (You can probably find a jquery plugin that will do that in one command.)

Alternatively, you can initialize the datatable when opening the tab. -- or by having a button which loads it manually. (I don't think that fnDraw calls the function shown above -- so the original -- incorrect width would still be loaded in the datatable config)

**EDIT**

I just came across [this link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html) which describes how to deal with datatables inside tabs.